# Group single variable vs. the rest of variables pooled together. Iterate over different variables

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

let's say I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
Variable    X     Y     Z
A           2     5     3
B           4     3     2
C           5     1     5
B           6     2     4
C           2     5     2
```

Using dplyr or any other suitable package, I would like to group by every single variable, compare it to the rest of the variables pooled together and compute a mathematical operation between the two resulting groups, let's say the sum along columns. I would get something like this:

```
Variable    X     Y     Z
A           2     5     3
rest        17    11    13

Variable    X     Y     Z
B           10    5     6
rest        9     11    10

Variable    X     Y     Z
C           7     6     7
rest        12    10    9
```

I have a large data.frame with hundreds of variables, so I would also like to do it in an iterative way. Any suggestion would be of great help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something along this ? (you can subset from a list)

```
l = lapply(unique(df$Variable), function(x) rbind(colSums(df[df$Variable == x,][c("X", "Y", "Z")]), 
                                                  colSums(df[df$Variable != x,][c("X", "Y", "Z")])))
#[[1]]
#      X  Y  Z
#[1,]  2  5  3
#[2,] 17 11 13

#[[2]]
#      X  Y  Z
#[1,] 10  5  6
#[2,]  9 11 10

#[[3]]
#      X  Y Z
#[1,]  7  6 7
#[2,] 12 10 9

names(l) = LETTERS[1:3]
l = lapply(l, function(x){rownames(x) = c("Variable", "Rest");x})
list2env(l, .Globalenv)  # this should load all dataframes separately
```

Comment: Thank you very much @joel.wilson. May I ask you what does "x" stand for?. I am getting an error in colSums --> 'x' must be numeric

Comment: @Lucas does your data have any other variable apart from what you specified? then it could error out.. i can resolve that

Comment: @Lucas also ensure that `df` is a `data.frame`

Comment: Yes @joel.wilson , as I mentioned I have a big data.frame with hundreds of variables. I have 3 columns of variables (v1, v2, v3) but I want to group them based on the variables from a specific column, e.g. v1. Many thanks

Comment: @Lucas i have edited. basically i have subsetted to have only those 3 columns

Comment: @Lucas seems the error messages suggested some of the columns contain non numeric data. the x refers the column, not x in function(x) .

Comment: why did i get a downvote here? why don't folks share their reviews!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go full `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Variable = c("A","B","C","B","C"),
             X = c(2,4,5,6,2),
             Y = c(5,3,1,2,5),
             Z = c(3,2,5,4,2))


group_summary <- function(data, var) {

   data %>%
    group_by_(group = ~ if_else(grepl(var, Variable), var, "rest")) %>%
    summarise_each_(funs(sum),~-Variable) %>% 
    rename_(.dots = setNames(c("group"), c("Variable")))
}

map(unique(df$Variable), ~group_summary(df, .x))


[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Variable  X     Y     Z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     A     2     5     3
2  rest    17    11    13

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Variable  X     Y     Z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     B    10     5     6
2  rest     9    11    10

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Variable  X     Y     Z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     C     7     6     7
2  rest    12    10     9
```

If you want a different output than a list you can explore the use of the different map functions (e.g `map_df`) and the use of `tibbles`

Comment: Thank you very much @Jake Kaupp. May I ask you what does ".x" stand for?

Comment: It's part of the approach utilized in `purrr::map()`.  In the call above, `unique(df$Variable)` is list of items that `group_summary()` will be applied to.   The `.x` is an explicit reference to that list.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jake Kaupp. Your solution works very nice. I gave the green check to joel.wilson because he posted a solution first.

Comment: As you should! I was just highlighting a different approach.

Comment: hey @JakeKaupp  went through the code!! awesome written.. i always like `tidyverse` approach +1